# Laravel Models Defining Columns Possible?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I just started playing with Laravel, and was wondering the following:

**Can you define your table structure in the model, then create a migration based off it? (The way Django works).**

```
 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


 class SomeListing extends Model
 {
     // Below V V V V Define Columns

     public $title = ''; // somehow make a string(255)?
     public $description = ''; // somehow make a text?

     // etc
     // etc
 }
```

Or must you always adjust the migration files? I could not find this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent).

Comment: Laravel does not has this feature yet. You have to write db table structure within migration file

Comment: Every time you want to make a physical change to your database structure that Laravel is based on, you have to make a migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it does not exist, but you can create migrations for your database with migrations

**Create migration**

```
php artisan make:migration create_table_name
```

and

```
php artisan migrate
```

More info could be found at [Laravel's Migration Document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations)